# Whats the normal markup for these CSS hover effects?

Tags: css

I am trying to copy some nice icon animations in the following link:

http://tympanus.net/Development/IconHoverEffects/#set-1

Since the site does not provide any instructions in doing it, I tried setting one locally but unfortunately failed. The best I could get was to show a blank `<a>`.

Can anyone explain when the icons are really rendered? I would very much appreciate it if someone can set up a fiddle or something. Thanks!

Comment: Could you explain what you're trying to do, what's in the link? And could you post the code you have written to try to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this example they used 'font-family: 'ecoicon';'
You can download full example from [**Github**](https://github.com/codrops/IconHoverEffects)

You can see attached [**ecoicon font here**](https://github.com/codrops/IconHoverEffects/tree/master/fonts/ecoicons).

**For hove effect:**
used `border-radius: 50%;` to get rounded shape and `transition` effect to get smooth background color change while hover the icon.

```
.hi-icon-effect-1 .hi-icon {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  -webkit-transition: background 0.2s, color 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: background 0.2s, color 0.2s;
  transition: background 0.2s, color 0.2s;
}
.hi-icon-effect-1a .hi-icon:hover {
  background: #FFF;
  color: #41AB6B;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The circles are rendered using `border-radius: 50%` and the icon images are characters in an "icon font" which is a method of including vector artwork in a site all in a single file. The icon font file is http://tympanus.net/Development/IconHoverEffects/fonts/ecoicons/ecoicon.woff

You can use the F12 tools present in every major web-browser to inspect a website.